# Can't extract files

Tags: extract

This error comes up when I try to extract the file or use it:

[image: screenshot of error]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to download the file again. This error most likely indicates a corrupt archive file.

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking the grey round tick button on its left. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Don't forget to take the [tour].